# Solving the following limit without L'Hospital's rule: $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin(x^2+2)-\sin(x+2)}{x} $

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry, limits-without-lhopital

> I have been trying to solve the following limit $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin(x^2+2)-\sin(x+2)}{x}.$$

I came across the right answer as shown by the steps below, but I would to check if the steps are correct or if someone has a more straightforward solution.

So applying the sum formula for sine and doing simple algebra we have:
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\cos{2} \,(\sin{x^2}-\sin{x})}{x} - \frac{\sin{2} (\cos{x^2}-\cos{x})}{x} .$$

The first limit is easy to evaluate and is equal to $-\cos{2}$. However, the second limit is harder, as it follows:
 $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin{2} (\cos{x^2}-\cos{x})}{x} .$$

I came across a solution by using the following sum-to-product identity:
$$\cos{A}-\cos{B}=-2\sin{\Big(\frac{A+B}{2}\Big)} \sin{\Big(\frac{A-B}{2}\Big)}$$

Setting $A=x^2$ and $B=x$, we have that
$$\cos{x^2}-\cos{x}=-2\sin{\Big(\frac{x^2+x}{2}\Big)} \sin{\Big(\frac{x^2-x}{2}\Big)}$$

This is my only point of concern whether I applied the identity correctly. The rest of it flows more easily:

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin{2} (\cos{x^2}-\cos{x})}{x} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{-2\sin{2}\,\sin{\Big(\frac{x^2+x}{2}\Big)} \sin{\Big(\frac{x^2-x}{2}\Big)}}{x}$$

$$= -2 \sin{2} \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin{\Big(\frac{x^2+x}{2}\Big)}}{x} \lim_{x\to 0} \sin{\Big(\frac{x^2-x}{2}\Big)} $$

The first limit can be solved as it follows:
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin{\Big(\frac{x^2+x}{2}\Big)}}{x} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin{\Big(\frac{x^2+x}{2}\Big)} \Big(\frac{x^2+x}{2}\Big)}{x \Big(\frac{x^2+x}{2}\Big)} = 1 \cdot \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^2 + x}{2x} = \frac{1}{2} $$

The second limit is equal to zero
 $$\lim_{x\to 0} \sin{\Big(\frac{x^2-x}{2}}\Big)=0$$

Comment: What about the $x$ in the denominator at the very end? Even if your numerator goes to zero, the denominator appears to as well ...

Comment: You have applied the identity correctly but I hope you know what steps are involved in making the two claims about the first limit being $-\cos 2$ and the second limit being $0$. Because they are not as simple as you have presented here.

Comment: The very end limit can be solved. I will edit the solution

Comment: @PeterForeman If L'Hospital, with derivatives, isn't allowed, Taylor series would hardly be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just sum-to-product it from the beginning and use $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\sin(x)/x = 1$:
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin(x^2+2)-\sin(x+2)}{x} &= \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{2\cos[2+x(x+1)/2]\sin[x(x-1)/2]}{x}
\\ & = \cos(2)\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin[x(x-1)/2]}{x/2}
\\ &= -\cos(2)\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin[x(x-1)/2]}{x(x-1)/2} 
\\ &= -\cos(2)
\end{align}

Comment: Yes, much shorter!

Answer (score 2):

The second limit is not really hard: leaving out the $\sin2$ factor, we have
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\cos(x^2)-\cos x}{x}=
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\cos(x^2)-1+1-\cos x}{x}
$$
It's easy to show that
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1-\cos x}{x}=0
$$
so we remain with
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\cos(x^2)-1}{x}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\cos(x^2)-1}{x^2}x
$$
which is zero for the same reason.

Comment: I did not follow your first step. Your first step gives $\frac{\cos^2{x}-cos{x}}{x}$, which differs from  $\frac{\cos{x^2}-\cos{x}}{x}$

Comment: @MarcosAlex Sorry, I had misread. Now it's OK.

Comment: What?! I liked the way you did it. Congrats!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

You can rewrite this fraction as
$$\frac{\sin(x^2+2)-\sin(x+2)}{x}=\frac{\sin(x^2+2)-\sin(2)}{x}-\frac{\sin(x+2)-\sin(2)}{x},$$
which is the difference of two rates of variation. Can take it from there?

Comment: No, I can not from there. Can you explain?

Comment: I'll try to make you find out. What is the limit of the rate of variation of a function?

Answer (score 0):

First notice that

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\cos x - 1}{x} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{2\sin^2\frac{x}2}{x} = \lim_{x\to 0} \left(\frac{\sin^2\frac{x}2}{\frac{x}2}\right)\cdot\sin\frac{x}2 = 1 \cdot 0 = 0$$
so

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{ \cos{x^2}-\cos{x}}{x} = \lim_{x\to 0} \left(\frac{\cos x^2-1}{x^2}\right)x + \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1-\cos x}{x} =  0$$

Finally we get

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin(x^2+2)-\sin(x+2)}{x} =\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\cos{2} \,(\sin{x^2}-\sin{x})}{x} - \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin{2} (\cos{x^2}-\cos{x})}{x}  = -\cos 2$$

Answer (score 0):

On applying Taylor series, and binomial expansion and taking linear degree terms in numerator to evaluate the limit,(all constant terms are powers of 2, they cancel out as they are same for both terms in numerator)

We get the limit as $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin(x^2+2)-\sin(x+2)}{x}. = -1 + \frac{{3} \choose {1} * 2^2}{3!} - \frac{{5} \choose {1} *2^4}{5!} \ldots =-(1-\frac{2^2}{2!}+\frac{2^4}{4!} \ldots)=-\cos(2)$

Comment: The 2^2,2^4 terms are outside the combination. I am not able to write that outside the 3C1 and 5C1 expression

Answer (score 0):

The second limit can be evaluated as follows:

$\quad \quad \quad \lim_{x\to0} \frac{sin2(cosx^2 - cosx)}{x}$

$\quad \quad \quad \lim_{x\to0} sin2 \cdot (\frac{cosx^2 - cosx}{x})$

$\quad \quad \quad \lim_{x\to0}  sin2 \cdot (\frac{cosx^2}{x} - \frac{cosx}{x})$

$\quad \quad \quad \lim_{x\to0} sin2 \cdot (\frac{1}{x} \cdot (cosx^2 - cosx))$

$\quad \quad \quad sin2 \cdot \lim_{x\to0} \frac{1}{x} \cdot \lim_{x\to0} (cosx^2-cosx)$

By the multiplication rule for limits

$\quad \quad \quad sin2 \cdot \lim_{x\to0} (\frac{1}{x} \cdot (cosx^2-cosx))$

Substituting  $x = 0$  for the latter expression

$\quad \quad \quad sin2 \cdot \lim_{x\to0} (\frac{1}{x} \cdot 0)$

$\quad \quad \quad sin2 \cdot \lim_{x\to0} (0)$

The second part is the limit of a constant, which is just the constant, therefore

$\quad \quad \quad sin2 \cdot 0$

Therefore, the entire second limit evaluates to $0$, and the answer to your question is the first limit; $-cos(2)$.